# How CNNs achieve spatial invariance despite having a Fully Connected layer at the end for classification?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

An image of a dog should be learnt by the network as being a dog irrespective of the spatial position and or rotation (maybe even deformation?). My question is how CNNs are able to achieve this? The convolution operations on input image successfully detect a feature that is characteristic of a particular label, but at the end for classification we have a FC layer which for one position of dog in image will receive a different set of inputs and for another position the input will be different. Precisely speaking-for different spatial positions of an object in the image, different neurons of the FC layer will get activated, so how is the network able to detect the presence of a dog in different positions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it is about machine learning rather than software development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291009/1233251). You can ask these questions on [Cross Validated](//stats.stackexchange.com) or [DataScience.SE](//datascience.stackexchange.com).